# Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'then' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

Does anyone know the cause of this error? I have tried many ways but still don't know where the problem is.

**Database.dart**

```
import 'package:fitness_app/Login/login_data.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  static final DatabaseService _databaseService = DatabaseService._internal();
  factory DatabaseService() => _databaseService;
  DatabaseService._internal();
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
   if (_database != null) return _database!;
   _database = await _initDatabase();
   return _database!;
}

 Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
   final databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
   final path = join(databasePath, 'conference.database');
   return await openDatabase(
     path,
     onCreate: _onCreate,
     version: 1,
     onConfigure: (db) async => await db.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON'),
 );
 }

Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute(
   'CREATE TABLE login(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, username TEXT, password TEXT)',
 );
}
verifyuser(String user, String pass) {}

insertLoginData(Logindata logindata) {}
}
```

**Login.dart**

```
import 'package:fitness_app/Login/signup.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login_data.dart';
import 'package:fitness_app/Database/database.dart';
import 'package:fitness_app/home_page.dart';


class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key, this.login}) : super(key: key);
  final Logindata? login;
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  String email = "a";
  String pass = "a";
  TextEditingController emails = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final List<Logindata> _login = [];
  final DatabaseService _databaseService = DatabaseService();

  Future<List<Logindata>> _getLogin() async {
    await _databaseService.verifyuser(email, pass).then((value) {
      if (value) {
        AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Login successful!'),
          content: const Text('Welcome!'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => (Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
              )),
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return alert;
          },
        );
      } else {
        AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Error!'),
          content: const Text('Wrong Email or Password'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return alert;
          },
        );
      }
    });
    return _login;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'BeFit:Fitness Activity Tracker Progress\n\n',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Welcome',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: emails,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                              labelText: 'Email'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Email is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: password,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                              labelText: 'Password'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Password is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 50,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              email = emails.text;
                              pass = password.text;
                              _getLogin();
                              print(email);
                              print(pass);
                              print('success');
                            }
                          },
                          child: Text("Login"),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Does not have account?'),
                          FlatButton(
                            textColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
                            child: Text(
                              'Sign up',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              //signup screen
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const SignUp()),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rnYC.png)

I'm using this flutter to complete my project but there are some errors that I can't solve it. Sorry if my coding looks not right because still lacks in coding

Comment: Welcome to So! Please [edit] your question to include your code as _text_ rather then as an image

Comment: You need to share the code where this is happening. You can only use then after Future, so that might be the problem without further information

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your `verifyuser` function does not return anything so your `value` returns `null`. You either need to return something or check for null values in your then statement.

```
Future<String> verifyuser(String user, String pass)async {
    return user + pass;
}
```

Comment: but it has an error at user+pass

Comment: Can you also mark varifuser as async. I've updated it